# Do I need to replace all the class file in hierarchy in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class `Animal` which has a tree of child classes.

If I am replacing the `Animal` class, Do I need to replace the child classes also ?

Comment: I think, you just need update packages. Production with Animals - is funny

Comment: It depends on what changes you've made to `Animal`.

Comment: You should not replace a class file in production. Package a new jar/war/ear/... and deploy that.

Comment: Well i have not edited any thing , Just removed some annotations from Animal(Well its just symbolic name) class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what do you mean by "replacing" the Animal class.

If you change the fields and methods of that class, then you must assure that the changes won't affect the way they behave in the child classes. Because all the child classes of the Animal class will **inherit** or **overwrite** all the fields and methods of the parent class.

By example, if you decide to rename a field variable of the class, then look up that variable in the child classes and rename it there also. If you want to remove a method, be sure that you won't use that method in one of your child classes.

I hope you get idea. In most cases if you do something wrong, you'll get some compile errors that are not hard to fix.